# What is the only number $N$ such that, between them, $N$ and $N^6$ contain every digit from $1$ to $9$ twice?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

What is the only number $N$ such that, between them, $N$ and $N^6$ contain every digit from $1$ to $9$ twice?

Comment: So $N$ and $N^6$ contain all digits from $1$ to $9$ exactly twice? That means that together they have $18$ digits, right?

Comment: wrong ! N+N^6=18.

Comment: That is to say, number of digits$(N+N^6)$ = $18$, right?

Comment: This question is not clear.

Comment: What about zero digits? I.e. if $N$ is a solution, how do you exclude $10 \times  N?$

Comment: I don't see how the terms "only number" and "between them" combine together into a statement that makes any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$314^6 = 958468597212736$. There are $2$ of each digit in this combination.

Comment: There is only one $1,3,4$

Comment: You have to include the $314$ also, which is the $N$ in this question. Hence $N$ and $N^6$ together contain every digit once.

Comment: I see. This might be the intended interpretation of the question.

Comment: explain how you had solved it?

Comment: Back to you: which is the only $N$ such that $N^6$ contains $15$ digits, and has  digital sequences $222$ and $22$ embedded in it? And which is the only one which has two $144$ sequences embedded in it? Solve this, and you'll see how I solved your question.